# Why when i write easy code in c i have a problem?

Tags: c

I'm learning c. I have a small problem which i can't resolve.

**If i write "int characterAge = 35;" and and after some lines i write "int characterAge = 20;", the programm outputs an error:
**

```
program.c: In function ‘main’:
program.c:11:7: error: redefinition of ‘characterAge’
   11 |   int characterAge = 20;
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
program.c:6:7: note: previous definition of ‘characterAge’ with type ‘int’
    6 |   int characterAge = 35;
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Whats wrong?

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
int main()
{
  char characterName[] = "John";
  int characterAge = 35;

  printf("Character name is %s\n", characterName);
  printf("Character age is %d\n", characterAge);

  int characterAge = 20;

  printf("He was %d\n", characterAge);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int characterAge`... *declares* the variable, which you can only do once.

Comment: The error means exactly what it says.  You're trying to *declare* (create) the same variable twice.  Did you just mean to *assign* (update) the value for that variable?: `characterAge = 20;`

Comment: @David: Re “exactly what it says. You're trying to *declare* (create)”: That is not exactly what it says. Exactly what it says is “definition,” not “declaration.” Those are different things, and declaring something does not necessarily create it. We have plenty of questions where we have to explain to students the difference between declarations that are not definitions and declarations that are, so this issue should not be muddled when they are just learning about declarations. Merely having two declarations of an identifier can be okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This creates a variable named `characterAge` (initalized to 35):

```c
int characterAge = 35;
```

This creates a second variable named `characterAge` (initalized to 20):

```c
int characterAge = 20;
```

You now have two variables named `characterAge`, and only one is accessible. This is definitely something worthy of a warning.

Either use a different name for the second variable

```c
int characterEarlierAge = 20;
printf("He was %d\n", characterEarlierAge);
```

or reuse the same variable

```c
characterAge = 20;
printf("He was %d\n", characterAge);
```

A third solution is to limit the scope of the variables.

```c
{
   const char *characterName = "John";
   int characterAge = 35;

   printf("Character name is %s\n", characterName);
   printf("Character age is %d\n", characterAge);
}

{
   int characterAge = 20;
   printf("He was %d\n", characterAge);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`int characterAge = 35;` is not an assignment. It is a declaration, and `= 35` specifies an initial value for `characterAge`. Further, a declaration with an initialization is also a definition; it directs the compiler to **create** the object. (A declaration that is not a definition merely tells the compiler **about** something without necessarily creating it.)

When the compiler sees `int characterAge = 20;`, you are telling it to give `characterAge` the **initial** value 20. But you earlier told it to give `characterAge` the initial value 35. One thing cannot have two initial values.

Nor can you create something twice. There should only be one definition for `characterAge`.

If you want to change the value of `characterAge` after its creation, you use an assignment:

```
characterAge = 20;
```